# Adding animate in and animate out classes with one menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering, for all you javascript and jquery guru's what would be my best way to tackle this problem. What I have is a navigation that is hidden via CSS to the bottom of the screen. I've managed to have it working as a toggle fine - which you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/olichalmers/Lby7vfdf/.

```
var body = $("body"); $("#menuBtn").click(function() {
body.toggleClass("showMenu");});
```

This obviously means that the menu slides up and down.

What my problem is is that I want to animate the menu up on the initial click, and then when you click the button again to close it I want the navigation window to slide up. Then when you click it again to open it, it is appearing from the bottom again. I've been trying to get my head around how this would work and what I think is that it would be two classes (one for hide menu, and one for show menu) which would be added and removed from the body. I have a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/olichalmers/twqd2yj0/

```
var body = $("body"); $("#menuBtn").click(function() {
      if (body.hasClass("hideMenu")) {
        body.removeClass("hideMenu").addClass("showMenu");
      }
      else if (body.hasClass("showMenu")) {
        body.removeClass("showMenu").addClass("hideMenu");
      }});
```

This is probably shocking in it's attempt to come to a solution to this problem. I'm using jquery but maybe it is a javascript solution using an event listener that is needed here? My jquery and javascript knowledge is patchy at best as i'm still in the midst of learning so please go easy if I appear very dumb!

Hope i've been clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to use http://jsfiddle.net/olichalmers/Lby7vfdf/2/? Clicking the icon has no effect on your original fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I think you have to enable jquery then run.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach?

Create your bottom menu in a separate DIV, located at very top of your HTML (directly under BODY tag). Make that DIV `position: fixed` -- that takes it out of the "flow" and positions it relative ot the viewport (the screen), not to any other divs or to the web page itself. Now, you can move it up/down based on some trigger.

Here is a code example:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgLd13v6/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="botttrig"></div>
<div id="bottmenu">The menu is here</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        <p>Content goes here</p>
        <p>Hover over small box at bottom left</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#botttrig').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('#bottmenu').animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
        },500);
    },
    function(){
        //do nothing on hover out
    }
);
$('#bottmenu').hover(
    function(){
        //do nothing on hover in
    },
    function(){
        $('#bottmenu').animate({
            'bottom': '-80px'
        },500);
        $('#botttrig').fadeIn();
    }
);
```

---

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgLd13v6/2/) for another example. I removed the trigger box, and left the top 10px of the menu visible at screen bottom. Upon hover, slide the menu up. You may wish to increase the z-index on the #bottmenu div to always display it above the other DIVs on the page, so that it is always visible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply gibberish. What i'm trying to do is better illustrated on this website - http://www.hugeinc.com/ . When you click the menu icon the first time it brings the nav in from the top (upon inspecting the code on the click it adds a class called open to nav) and then when you click the same icon again it removes the class open and adds a class called closing, then removes that class once the animation is finished. The process of adding two separate classes consecutively from the same button is what i'm after.

Comment: Adding a class will move the div. But I don't know if you can animate by adding a class...? Perhaps by using a transition...? Not by jQuery animate though.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/twqd2yj0/4/

I've used [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and added `display:none;` to #navHold